# Tkinterにおいて、最前面に表示したウィンドウのタイトルを取得したい

Tags: python, python3, tkinter, tk

Python3, Tkinterを用いてアプリケーション開発をしています。
開発アプリケーション内にて複数のウィンドウを使用し、ウィンドウごとに
別の動作をするようにしたいです。
その際、サブウィンドウをリスト化し、タイトルがインデックスと同じになるように
することでサブウィンドウの区別をしました。

そこで、最前面にあるウィンドウのタイトルを取得したいが
その方法が分からないため困っています。

サンプルコードにおけるゴール: サブウィンドウを2つ生成した後に
タイトル**sub_window_0**をクリックし最前面に表示し
その後タイトル**sub_window_0**という値を取得

以下、サンプルコードになります。

```
import tkinter as tk

class make_window():

    def __init__(self):
        self.win_li = []
        self.i = 0
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("make_window")

        self.b = tk.Button(self.root, text="make_sub_window", command=self.button_event)
        self.b.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()


    def button_event(self):
        sub_win = tk.Toplevel()
        title = "sub_window_#" + str(self.i)
        sub_win.title(title)
        self.win_li.append(sub_win)
        self.i += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    app = make_window()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

各Windowの管理や処理内容の分岐などに注意を払う必要がありますが、このような実装ではいかがでしょうか？
Titleテキストで判断が可能です。
また、各Windowでの各Entryウィジットへのフォーカスも試してみました。
main windowへフォーカスが移ったことも判断できます。

サブウィンドウは、メインと異なる動きだと思いますので、クラス化して実装したほうが良いと思います。

```
import tkinter as tk


class main_window():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = self._create_window_()
        self._create_widget_(self.root)
        self.event_bind(self.root)

        self.sub_window_cnt = 0

        self.root.mainloop()
        return

    def _create_window_(self):
        root = tk.Tk()

        title = 'main window'

        root.title(title)
        root.minsize(300, 200)

        return root

    def _create_widget_(self, root):
        self.btn_create_sub_widow = tk.Button(
            root,
            text="create sub window",
            command=self.btn_create_sub_widow_cliecked
        )

        self.btn_create_sub_widow.pack()

        return

    def event_bind(self, root):
        root.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda x: self.foucus_in(root))
        root.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda x: self.foucus_out(root))

        root.deiconify()
        root.lift()
        root.focus_force()

    def btn_create_sub_widow_cliecked(self):
        self.sub_window_cnt += 1
        root = tk.Toplevel()
        root.title(f"sub window #{self.sub_window_cnt}")
        root.minsize(300, 200)
        entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
        entry1.pack()
        entry1.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda x: self.entry_foucus_in(entry1))
        entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
        entry2.pack()
        entry2.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda x: self.entry_foucus_in(entry2))

        self.event_bind(root)

        return

    def foucus_in(self, root):
        print("foucus_in", root.title())
        return

    def foucus_out(self, root):
        print("foucus_out", root.title())
        return

    def entry_foucus_in(self, Widget):
        print("entry foucus_in", Widget.get())
        return


main_window()
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事解決いたしました。また、main_windowにもevent_bind関数を適用することでフォーカスの移りを追いかけることができました！